# Truncate Pagination with PHP

Tags: php, html, pagination

Hi there i'm trying to develop pagination however my numbers are overflowing.
I'd like it to be < 1234..15 > for example. I know there are a few examples on here but, I can't fully grasp what they're doing in there examples and relate it to mine. So basically where and how can I write that if statement with the following code?

```
<?php
    $url = $this->url('stack-overflow');

    $next_data = $links['next_data'];

    $next_button = $links['current_page'] + 1;
    $prev_button = $links['current_page'] - 1;
    ?>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-circle pg-blue">
            <?php
            if ($links['current_page'] > 1) {
            ?>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $prev_button ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
            //Loop through total pages
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $links['total_pages']; $i++) {
                if ($i === $links['current_page']) {
                ?>
                    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a></li>
                <?php
                } else {
                ?>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a></li>
                <?php
                }
            }

            if (!empty($next_data)) {
                ?>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $next_button ?>" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hey @Marcel , my question is how can I truncate the numbers with my code. I'm not sure how to write that if statement and where. Should I subtract something from current page i'm really confused.

Comment: With your code, if there were 1000 pages, your paginator would display all of them, isn't?
I would pick 5 below and 5 above for example.
In order to achieve that, you need to perform checks current page below 5 is not less than 1 and the opposite with the inverse. And I would do two for loops, one for each situation

Answer (score 3):

You have to take into mind the different possibilities.

The code is quite dirty, I recommend you to implement a Paginator library to avoid all this spagetti code.

```php
<?php
    $url = $this->url('stack-overflow');

    $next_data = $links['next_data'];

    $next_button = $links['current_page'] + 1;
    $prev_button = $links['current_page'] - 1;
    ?>

    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-circle pg-blue">
        <?php
        if ($links['current_page'] > 1) {
        ?>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $prev_button ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        // Below pages
        $pagesToShow = 5;
        if ($links['current_page'] > 1) {
            for ($i = 1; $i >= $links['current_page']; $i++) {
                if ($pagesToShow === $i) break;
                $pagesToShow++;

                if ($i === $links['current_page']) {
                ?>
                    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a></li>
                <?php
                break;
                } else {
                ?>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a></li>
                <?php
                }
            }
        }

        // Above
        if ($links['current_page'] !== $links['total_pages']) {
            for ($i = $links['current_page'] + 1; $i >= $links['total_pages']; $i++) {
                if ($pagesToShow === $i) break;
                $pagesToShow++;
                ?>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a></li>
                <?php
                }
            }
        }

        if ($links['current_page'] + $pagesToShow <= $links['total_pages']) {
            ?>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="<?= $url . '?page=' . $next_button ?>" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    </nav>
}
```